# How to break an image to subimages?

Tags: java, image, image-processing

What is the shortest code one can write in java to break an image (say 200x1000) into 10 images of a tenth height but same width (200x 100)?

Mine is a pretty long code; the main part , I am just giving:

```js
for (int i_=0;i_<10;i_++)
            {
                for(int k=i_*100;k<i_*100+h/10;k++)
                    {
                        for(int j_=0;j_<w;j_++)
                            {
        
                                int pixv=img.getRGB(j_,k);
                                r=(pixv>>16)&0xff;
                                g=(pixv>>8)&0xff;
                                b=(pixv)&0xff;
                                int rgb=new Color(r,g,b).getRGB();
                                img.setRGB(j_,k-i_*200,rgb);
                             }
                     }
                 // Here I am writing the img to a new .bmp file thus creating 10 seperate files
             }
```

Here img is a BufferedImage

w,h the width and height of large image

Comment: What have you tried? Nobody can do your (home)work until you show some efforts.

Comment: I would rather bother about the three nested for loops than the int r g b part

Comment: @Jankapunkt By long ,I meant to say I myself understand I have used many useless extra things I might have not needed to..

Comment: @Raúl : I have edited my question to show my work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get a sub image from BufferedImage using getSubimage(int x,int y,int w,int h). Try this:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class NewClass9 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
  BufferedImage img = null;
  img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\users\\uzochi\\desktop\\Penguins.jpg"));
  for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
    BufferedImage sub = img.getSubimage(0, i*(img.getHeight()/10), img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()/10);
    File f = new File("C:\\users\\uzochi\\desktop\\SubImage"+i+".png");
    ImageIO.write(sub, "png", f);
  }
}
```

}